# Child and Lights on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, minor-katan-child

Can you put a child who is not yet old enough to understand *(lo higyah lichinuch)* Shabbos in front of a light switch in order that he or she turn the light off or on? Is there a difference between the two: turning the light off versus turning it on? (This question is about lights in particular.)

Comment: Why do you suspect that lights may be special in this regard and that therefore this question is distinct from http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/4872/may-a-katan-minor-perform-melachah-work-on-shabbath ?

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol26Zivotofsky.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is based wholly on *Children in Halacha* by Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen (Artscroll, 1st ed.), chapters 1 and 4:

The age of *chinuch* for forbidden activities is from when a kid will not do something later if you tell him now that it's the kind of thing he can't do. This is about age four. From that age, you cannot allow your kid to do any *m'lacha* on *Shabas*. Until that age, it's okay if your kid does (and even if you encourage your kid to do) *m'lacha d'rabanan*, not *d'oraysa*, provided he's (to his mind) doing it for his own benefit.

Turning off an incandescent bulb is a *d'rabanan*; turning one on is a *d'oraysa*.

Comment: "Turning off an incandescent bulb is a d'rabanan; turning one on is a d'oraysa." - Please explain. Mechabe is d'oraysa (turning off the light reduces the flame at the power generator). Perhaps you were thinking of the building a circuit part?

Comment: כיבוי here is melacha Sheena tsricha legufa

Answer (score 2):

One cannot do an Issur D'Rabbanan by means of a child(Shulchan Arukh 309:1 also see Mishna Berurra there), such as carrying muktze, kal v'homer one can not violate an Av Malakha(Kindling or Extinguishing both are Av Malakhot) by means of a child.  A light may be extinguished for the sake of an ill person for whom there is danger(Shulchan Arukh 278:1)

> **It is muter to extinguish a candle to
>   enable a sick person at risk to fall
>   asleep.**

However Mishnah Berurra 1 says that this only applies after all other options have been exhausted.
Also in that particular vein of thought one must consider what is written in the Shulchan Arukh 328:12

> **When violating the Shabbos for the
>   sake of pikuach nefesh, gentiles,
>   children and women should not be used,
>   rather it should be violated by adults
>   and mature males.** RAMA *Some are of
>   the opinion that if it is possible to
>   make a shinui without causing any
>   delay, one should. If it is possible
>   to use gentiles without causing a
>   delay, one should use a gentile, and
>   such is the custom. When there is room
>   to believe that the gentile will dally
>   then a gentile must not be used.*

The Halakha is quite clear for Sephardim and all of the major poskim hold verbatim by the Mechaber.  By Ashkenazim it gets a little more complicated, however the Mishnah Berurrah 37 and Rav S.Z. Auerbach, as brought in Shmirat Shabbat Kehilchata 32:28 rule in accordance with Mechaber.

As far as having a child extinguish a fire in any case there are the Mishna Berurrahs brought on the Shulchan Arukh 334:26, as well as the Kaf HaChaim there, and the Yalkut Yosef 334:18.

In short using a child to perform an Av Melakha even in a case of Pikuach Nefesh is highly problematic.

Comment: I am guessing based on your answer 2 things it is only good for off and only when you need it to sleep?

Comment: Considering that both extinguishing and kindling are Av Malakhot of Shabbat, I don't know that it makes a difference in that respect.  This issue is relieving the tza'ar of the child, who is considered al pi halakha to be ill until a certain age.

Comment: I meant somthing along the lines of I want to Read in A room and the light is off so I hold a kid next to switch for him to turn it on?

Comment: That would definitely be a problem.

Comment: many see extinguishing an incandescent lightbulb as not the melacha d'oraita of extinguishing.  This is likely based on melacha sh'eino tzricha l'gufa.  He is not turning off the light to create a coal that will light easier later.  Turning on the light is more similar to the purposes for which the av melacha of igniting was performed.  It is on this basis that people say turning on is a d'oraita and off is not.

Comment: This Michael Tzadok is a RASHA , SINNER AND MAKES OTHER SIN, HE'S NOT JEWISH, HE'S A MISSIONARY, WATCH A MENUVAL UGH!!!  WATCH THIS VIDEO FROM RABBI TUVIA SINGER - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8g71VZrjCpg