# Is it permissible to get a toddler to push an electrical button on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, baby-infant

Am I allowed to manipulate a 2 or 3 year old to turn on or off a light on Shabbos? Or to turn on or off the air conditioner or heater? If allowed, how direct can I be in manipulating the toddler to push the button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Child and Lights on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/child-and-lights-on-shabbos)